# CLUSTER USING for Postgres in Django (table defragmenting / packing)

Tags: postgresql, django-models

Let's say that I'm building a stack exchange clone, and every time I examine a question, I also load each and every answer.  The table might look like:

```
id          integer
question_id FOREIGN KEY
answer      bool
date        timestamp
```

How can I tell django to tell postgres to keep all the answers together for fast access?  Postgres has the underlying feature [CLUSTER USING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-analyze.html).

(CLUSTER USING is 'defragmenting' feature for tables. This works especially well for small records, since they may all end up in the same disk block and greatly reduce load time.  The defragmenting is typically done as a batch job at times of low load).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't.  But you can treat this as a database administration task, and do it from the psql command line:

```
# CLUSTER table USING index_name;
# ANALYZE VERBOSE table;
# CLUSTER VERBOSE;
```

This will be remembered.  Each time you run CLUSTER VERBOSE it will lock all the tables and sort the data.  All your answers (in the example above) will be gathered together on disk.  This makes sense even for solid state storage, since the eventual database read will cover fewer sectors, meaning fewer I/O operations to retrieve the group.

Obviously you must pick your index well: the wrong choice can scatter the data you actually access.  The performance benefit is the best for sparse datasets, and becomes less relevant if most everything is frequently accessed.

A better name for the CLUSTER feature might be "DEFRAG", as this is an operation analogous defragmenting a filesystem.